# When starting application in OpenShift, encounter No such file or directory error with IPC namespace

Tags: python, docker, openshift

After containerizing an old python application into docker image, we tried to deploy the image to OpenShift. The container is built using docker file as below, and UBI8 as base image. The python package used comes together with the application

Dockerfile:

```
FROM my.artifactory.company.com/ubi8:latest
WORKDIR /appl/web/myapp

COPY myapp /appl/web/myapp

EXPOSE 8585
```

The Deployment pulls the image and execute the following:

```
      lifecycle:
        postStart:
          exec:
            command:
              - /appl/web/myapp/python-2.7/bin/python
              - /appl/web/myapp/supervisor/supervisor.py
              - echo Attemp to run supervisor
```

The pod failed to start and the following error is found:

> Exec lifecycle hook ([/appl/web/myapp/python-2.7/bin/python
> /appl/web/myapp/supervisor/supervisor.py echo Attemp to run
> supervisor]) for Container "myapp" in Pod
> "myapp-684b6878b4-cm979_my-app-namespace(83d1713d-4c78-404d-ad1b-8ab89fc5fc7a)" failed - error: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = command error:
> time="2024-03-11T15:11:06Z" level=fatal msg="nsexec-1[2194562]: failed
> to open /proc/2194510/ns/ipc: No such file or directory"
> time="2024-03-11T15:11:06Z" level=fatal msg="nsexec-0[2194561]: failed
> to sync with stage-1: next state: Invalid argument"
> time="2024-03-11T15:11:06Z" level=error msg="exec failed: unable to
> start container process: error executing setns process: exit status 1"
> , stdout: , stderr: , exit code -1, message: ""

The application is running using python2 and listen to a tcp port.

Been trying to look for how OpenShift handle the IPC namespace but could not find any definitive answer to this one. Any info would be appreciated.

***UPDATE***
Switching over to use `CMD` in the `Dockerfile`, i'm getting the following error instead:

```
/bin/sh: /appl/web/myapp/python-2.7/bin/python: Permission denied
```

The updated `Dockerfile` as below:

```
FROM my.artifactory.company.com/ubi8:latest
WORKDIR /appl/web/myapp

COPY myapp /appl/web/myapp

EXPOSE 8585 
CMD /appl/web/myapp/python-2.7/bin/python /appl/web/myapp/supervisor/supervisor.py
```

Comment: Your Dockerfile doesn't seem to have a `CMD`.  What is the main process in the container?  (You shouldn't normally need to create a container and separately use a hook mechanism to run its main process.)

Comment: @DavidMaze the main process is the command that i put in the hook.

Comment: That's a secondary command that gets run after the container actually starts; IME it's a little unusual to need that.  I'd move this command to the Dockerfile's `CMD` if you can, or Kubernetes `args:` if you can't.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for the suggest. I'd moved to use CMD, and now facing permission error. Had updated my question.